Proving $\Bbb{E}[\frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}]>0$, for $X$ a positive random variable with compact support, $\mu=\Bbb{E}[X]$, and $\lambda\geq 1$
Let $X$ be a positive random variable with compact support and let $\mu=\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]$.
Consider the following inequality involving the parameter $\lambda\geq 1$:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}\right]>0$$
Is there a straightforward way to prove this inequality?

Use @Zhanxiong's idea.
Let $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Y \sim X$.
We have, for all $X, Y > 0$,
$$(Y - X)\left(\frac{1}{(\mu+X)^\lambda} - \frac{1}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda}\right) \ge 0$$
or
$$[(\mu - X) - (\mu - Y)]\left(\frac{1}{(\mu+X)^\lambda} - \frac{1}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda}\right) \ge 0
$$
or
$$\frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}
- \frac{\mu-Y}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}
- \frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda}
+ \frac{\mu-Y}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda} \ge 0.$$
Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}
- \frac{\mu-Y}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}
- \frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda}
+ \frac{\mu-Y}{(\mu+Y)^\lambda}\right] \ge 0$$
which results in
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mu-X}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}\right] \ge 0$$
where we use
$$\mathrm{E}\left[\frac{\mu-Y}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}\right] = \mathbb{E}[\mu - Y]
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(\mu+X)^\lambda}\right] = 0.$$

Thanks for the answer

@Eastwood94 You are welcome.
